# Shifting values for 1...N previous months as separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'proj': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'date': ['2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-09-01'],
    'value': [10, 3, 15, 16, -20, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0]
})
```

[image: data]

and at the end I would like to have:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({
    'proj': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'date': ['2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-09-01'],
    'value': [10, 3, 15, 16, -20, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0],
    'prev_month_value': [np.NaN, 10, 3, 15, 16, -20, np.NaN, 1, 3, 3],
    'prev_prev_month_value': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 10, 3, 15, 16, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, 3]
})
```

[image: expected]

How to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) inside a dict comprehension and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) the results after:

```
N = 2

g = data.groupby('proj')
u = pd.DataFrame({
    ('prev_'*i) + 'month_value': g['value'].shift(i) for i in range(1, N + 1)})
pd.concat([data, u], axis=1)

 proj        date  value  prev_month_value  prev_prev_month_value
0    A  2018-08-01     10               NaN                    NaN
1    A  2018-09-01      3              10.0                    NaN
2    A  2018-10-01     15               3.0                   10.0
3    A  2018-11-01     16              15.0                    3.0
4    A  2018-12-01    -20              16.0                   15.0
5    A  2019-01-01      2             -20.0                   16.0
6    B  2018-06-01      1               NaN                    NaN
7    B  2018-07-01      3               1.0                    NaN
8    B  2018-08-01      3               3.0                    1.0
9    B  2018-09-01      0               3.0                    3.0
```